# Stubbing existing object's method in RSpec test

Tags: object, rspec, stub, chain, defined

I'm using Mandrill to send emails, and I defined $m in itinializer:

```
$m = Mandrill::API.new 'XmylongkeygoeshereTg'
```

I need to test a function that send an email, so I need to stub the `$m.messages.send` method somehow on that existing object. I read that `stub_chain` is a messy way to achieve that, but even that didn't work. Another way I tried was with `allow($m.messages).to` like that:

```
 it "sends emails to a group" do
   # stub Mandril's email sending, so no actual emails will be sent.
   allow($m.messages).to receive(:send) { nil }
   expect(subject.my_sending_emails_method).to be_true
 end
```

While there's no error, there's also no effect of stubbing - the emails are still being sent.

Please suggest how to stub it?

Answer (score 1):

There might be more than one answer, but what I found working is:

```
allow($m).to receive_message_chain(:messages, :send) { nil }
```

Comment: You method is good, and I have an error, so it worked like `$m.send`